# Prove that an idempotent element must be either 0, 1 or a zero-divisor.

Tags: ring-theory, idempotents

This is what I've come up with for the proof, but I feel like I'm missing a huge piece of the puzzle here. Any thoughts?

Proof. Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and let $a\in R$ be any idempotent. Then,

$a^{2}=a\Longrightarrow a^{2}-a=a(a-1)=0$

Since there cannot be any zero divisors in $R$ it follows that $a=0$ or $a-1=0\Rightarrow a=1$ as desired.

Now, if $R$ is not an integral domain we need show that for any nonzero $a\in R$ with the property that $a^{2}=a$, then $a$ is a zero-divisor.

If $a\ne1$, then $a^{2}=a\Rightarrow a(a-1)=0$. So either $a=0$ or $a=1$, but by assumption $a\ne 0$. So $a$ is a zero-divisor. QED

Comment: This isn't clear...do you mean to assume that $a$ is neither $0$ not $1$ in the second part?  If so, then since you have written $a(a-1)=0$ it is obvious that $a$ is a zero divisor,  But if you do not exclude $a=1$ then the statement as written is false.

Comment: If you look above case 1 I've assumed $a$ is nonzero.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't assume that $a\neq 1$.

Comment: Ah, good catch, I assumed it is not a unit but did not add the detail that $a\ne1$.

Comment: I see your edit, but it doesn't fix the error.  Your statement "if $R$ is not an integral domain we need show that for any nonzero $a\in R$ with the property that $a^{2}=a$, then $a$ is a zero-divisor." is incorrect.  You need to assume that $a\neq 0,1$.

Comment: I think we are arguing semantics at this point. Whether I assume it in that line or the following I feel it says the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to use as many cases.

$a(a-1) = 0$ as you noted, so if neither $a$ nor $a-1$ is $0$, i.e. $a$ is neither $0$ nor $1$, then $a$ is a zero divisor since $a(a-1) = 0$ and neither term is $0$.

Comment: So using case 1 is trivial and need not be addressed?

Comment: @MrStormy83 it’s not that it’s trivial: it’s that it is subsumed in the second half of the proof. It’s superfluous.